# DELETE Not Found con Postman en APIREST NodeJs con Mongo y Mongosoe

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, express, mongoose

¿Qué tal compañeros? estoy trabajando en una api rest con NodeJs, MongoDB y Mongoose, pero al implementar DELETE por Id, el postman me envia un error

```
Cannont DELETE /api/product/5aae8f9df40f3924a4b984f
```

En el status del Postman envía un 404 not found Mi código en el index.js para el delete, es el siguiente.

```
The resource could not be found but may be available again in the future
```

Mi código en el index.js para el DELETE es:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Product = require('./modelos/producto')

const app = express() 
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.delete('api/product/:productId', (req, res) => {

let productId = req.params.productId

Product.findById(productId,(err, product) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al borrar el producto ${err}`})
    product.remove(err => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send({message: `Error al borrar el producto ${err}`})
             res.status(200).send({message: `Producto eliminado`})
        })
    })
})
```

Mi POST y GET funciona perfectamente y en GET igual llamo por ID sin problema. Gracias de antemano compañeros.

Answer (score 0):

En la ruta falta el "/" delante de api, quedaría:

```
app.delete('/api/product/:productId', (req, res) => {
```